# OMV as VM: cyclic disk access

Tags: debian, ubuntu, hard-disk, kvm

I'm running openmediavault (OMV) 5.5.23-1 on Debian 10 (4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64). It runs in a QEMU/KVM virtual machine on a Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-70-generic x86_64) host which mainly acts as HTPC.

A while ago I noticed a cyclical noise (disk access?) with an interval of about 4 to 8 seconds. First I guessed that my WD Green which contains the HTPC data and the OMV VM files was about to die (click of death). Therefore I replaced it with a WD Red and copied all the data onto it. But the cyclical noise is still there. Only when I stop the OMV virtual machine the noise stops.

The PC contains the following disks now:

- Samsung SSD: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (`/` and `/home` on separate partitions)
- WD Red 3TB: HTPC data and VM files (`/` and `/home` of OMV as two separate
  qcow2 files)
- WD Red 2TB: NAS/OMV data disk
- WD Red 4TB: NAS/OMV backup disk

The disk setup inside the VM looks like this:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   32G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 30,5G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0 1021M  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0    8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0    8G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
vda    254:0    0  1,8T  0 disk /srv/dev-disk-by-label-nas-data
vdb    254:16   0  3,7T  1 disk /srv/dev-disk-by-label-nas-backup
```

What could cause this cyclic access/noise or how can I track it down?

When I do a `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump` and `dmesg` some seconds later the dump looks like this:

https://pastebin.com/0dLizPZx

Is there anything special in these entries?

Answer (score 0):

This regular sound reminds me of some power management feature that puts the drive in standby/sleeping mode while retracting the heads (this would be the sound you hear).

You hear it repeatedly because at regular intervals, the system flushes its caches and writes things onto the disk, which makes the drive wake up. Then, after a moment of inactivity, the drives goes back to standby/sleeping mode again.

You can check the power management mode of your HDD with `hdparm -B /dev/sd...`. You can monitor the PM mode your HDD is in with `hdparm -C /dev/sd...` (you may want to monitor it in a loop and see if the change in PM mode matches with the sound you hear).

Finally, you can disable PM altogether with `hdparm -B255 /dev/sd...` (this is a useful test to check that the "sound" disappears when PM is off but, as this is rather extreme, for everyday use you may prefer PM values between 128 and 254 -- see [`hdparm` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hdparm.8.html)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. See hdparm outputs for host and guest here: https://pastebin.com/EXw1Pt7g

Comment: You should add this to your question. I don't know why APM is not supported on your sdx disks. Please read again my note about monitoring APM state change until you hear the sound.

Comment: I monitored the state of each disk with `watch -n0.1 sudo hdparm -C /dev/sdx` and it returns `drive state is:  active/idle` all the time, on the host as well as on the guest. Only for vdx on the guest it returns `drive state is:  unknown`.

Comment: @pikim Thanks for the test and sorry that it didn't lead anywhere. My hypothesis is about real hardware, so running hdarm on a virtual disk (vda) makes no sense: it must be run on the host. I'm sorry my answer didn't help you find out the source of the noise. It's very strange you get "not supported" with "hdparm -B". I only get this with SSDs or virtual drives and my HDDs do return something.